# How do I improve my asp.net site when the Google speed test says "expiration not specified"?

Tags: asp.net, performance, pagespeed

I have taken different speed tests, including using [Google's PageSpeed Insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights).  For every image on every page, it warned me that I should specify heights and widths on every image, but more importantly, it said "**expiration not specified**" after every image.  It provided a link to suggestions on how to fix this, like use **HTTP cache headers**, but I didn't understand this at all.  I have 47 pages, many of them have 10+ pictures on a page.

All the images are optimized, but since I'm on an asp.net website with 5 master pages, what can I do?  I've seen solutions for php pages.  I don't even know what "expiration not specified" means.  Is there something I should just put in the head of my master pages, or do I need to do some type of coding on every image in my website?  Any guidance in this regard would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your IIS settings so that, when it's serving up your image files (or other, interesting, static content) it sets an appropriate cache expiry value.

[This article](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/staticcontent/clientcache) starts poorly, tending to indicate that you need to pick a single fixed value for expiry and place it in a config file. But it later shows a screenshot:

[image]

with some more hopeful looking options.

Comment: Thank you Damien for your help -- it worked perfectly and got rid of the expiration errors.  The IIS screenshot was especially helpful, and I appreciate the link!  At first, I got a "lock violation" error, but I just kept trying, and eventually it altered my web.config properly.  Again, thank you for taking the time to respond to my issue -- appreciate the knowledge!